# Where is the source code for `ForEach` method of a List<T> object?

Tags: c#, list, github, .net-core

I can't seem to find it in their github repository. If someone could be so kind as to find the definitions to it, I'd appreciate it.

Closest I've got is the [following](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/ref/System.Collections.cs#L302) partial class definition (method definition at [L340](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/ref/System.Collections.cs#L340).)

**EDIT:** I don't see why this was closed. I'm not asking for any recommendations. I'm asking for help in finding a given line of code, in a huge open source project.

Comment: 10 seconds on Google led me to this: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/a7bd3242bd7732dec4aebb21fbc0f6de61c2545e/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L545

Comment: @Sean Reference source is nice and all, but are you sure this is the exact code used in the .net core framework? That's why I tried to find the code directly in their github repository, rather than looking up .net Framework code.

Comment: Maybe you could explain to us why you're looking for the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs
i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

That can be found in Microsoft's [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for the .NET Framework. A quick search for `.NET ForEach source` came up with it. [Here's the bit you might be interested in](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,545)

The .NET Core version is also [available](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,570) as a convenient source browser.

You can also find it where you were looking for, in the [`dotnet/runtime`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) repo over [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/83b76b2b27077e9ebfa8fb8f9b23f21959e5d382/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L549). Apparently, `mscorlib` is, as far as I can tell (didn't investigate profusely), mapped to `System.Private.CoreLib`. That's where you'll probably find the sources for any `mscorlib` related things (e.g. code for `List<T>`).

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't search on reference source, as perhaps the coreFX team might have modified something, even if slightly. Sources there are for as you said, .NET Framework.

Do you have any idea if the source code used there is indeed the same used in .net core? That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: I just found where the source is in the `dotnet/runtime` repo. Updating my answer with it!

Comment: As far as if the code is the same in .NET Core, I would assume so, for the sake of code reuse. I'm 99% sure .NET Core uses `mscorlib`, meaning the code will definitely be the same.

**EDIT:** In fact, scratch that. Microsoft [does alledge `dotnet/runtime`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/dd4c17878c2c74157102fbbd77b88a08da58db7c/README.md) is used for the development of .NET Core, so. Yeah, now it's a question of trusting them that is the *actual* code ;)

Comment: The .NET Framework code and .NET Core code are definitely _not_ the same, so this doesn't correctly answer @SpiritBob's question. Moreover, the link here for the .NET Core version isn't even for `List<T>`; that link is for a random "list" class in WPF. The correct link, to `System.Private.CoreLib` on GitHub, can be found in @user13245024's answer.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed the .NET Core link (I haven't the slightest clue how a WPF class link got there, it's been a while). I'm sure .NET Core code and .NET Framework code isn't *entirely* the same, however there must be a shared basis, especially in this simple scenario of a generic data structure such as a list. In fact, looking at both concrete examples, now correctly linked to above, very little differs. And I don't believe it even constitutes a fair comparison w.r.t. versioning. Nonetheless, I'm sure other components from either versions differ plenty.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link. The reason I point out they aren't the same is that they _aren't_ the same: The reference source has extra comparisons in that loop, for example, and it will produce different behavior in .NET Framework 4.0 and earlier than you'll see in later versions or in .NET Core (or in .NET 5+). Other parts of `List<T>` differ considerably more; as a good example, `List<some struct>.Clear()` runs in O(n) time in .NET Framework, but in O(1) time in .NET Core 3+! Changes like that can have a huge impact, so having the right source matters.

Comment: Interesting, I would assume there would be differences at a much larger scale, but from your example, it baffles me that runtime complexity is different. Where did you find `List<T>.Clear()`'s runtime complexity? Both sources point to `Array.Clear`. .NET Core's version is implemented in C# as an unsafe method, but .NET Framework's is an extern definition (guessing impl is C++). Where could the source for the latter be found?